# Unable to connecting to documentDB in ec2 through setting SSL in spring boot 2.6.7

Tags: spring, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-documentdb

Here is my java config class

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    public static final String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "classpath:keystore/rds-truststore.jks";
    public static final String DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "amara9972871374";
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    String username = "amara";
    String password = "amara9972871374";
    String clusterEndpoint = "docdb-2023-08-04-09-33-14.cluster-cberolnffpii.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com";
    String readPreference = "secondaryPreferred";
    int port = 27017;
    String connectionString = String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d/amara?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readpreference=%s",
            username, password, clusterEndpoint, port, readPreference);

    ConnectionString connString = new ConnectionString(connectionString);
    setSslProperties();
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connString)
            .build();

    return MongoClients.create(settings);
}

private static void setSslProperties() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", KEY_STORE_TYPE);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",
            DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
}

@Bean
public MongoDatabase mongoDatabase(MongoClient mongoClient) {
    return mongoClient.getDatabase("amara");
}
```

I have rds-trustore.jks keystore file stored in src/main/resource/keystore

I tried setting the properties in application.properties but it does not work

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=classpath:keystore/rds-truststore.jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=amara9972871374
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
```

When I tried setting it in the above config file i got the following error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload the errors as text and not as images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors